# Splunk query to get all counts including events (_raw) where match does not exist

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

How do I get a count of all records for a given field including a count of all records where the field does not exist.

For example:

Given data that generally looks something like this:

```
{"source_host":"host1", "msg":"some message", "user":"jack"}
{"source_host":"host2", "msg":"some other message", "user":"jill"}
```

I can get a count of all records like this:

```
index="my_index" sourcetype=my_proj:my_logs | table _raw | stats count(_raw)
```

I can get a count of records for a given field like this:

```
index="my_index" sourcetype=my_proj:my_logs | stats count(_raw) by source_host
```

Gives a table like this

```
host       count
host_1     89
host_2     57
```

But I would like the query to also count records where the field exists but is empty, like this:

```
{"source_host":"", "msg":"some message", "user":"jack"}
```

And also count messages like this:

```
asdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasdfasdfafas 
foo bar
Some other Junk someone wrote to my log
```

To get a table like this

```
host       count
host_1     89
host_2     57
null       1
no_def     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fillnull` thusly ([docs.Splunk](https://docs.splunk.com) page for [fillnull](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fillnull)):

```
| fillnull value="N/A" <field or field list or leave blank for all fields>
```

In anything other than trivial searches, however, this will be *very* timeconsuming

Note: you can use a different `value=""` if you like

Answer (score 1):

The `case` function may help.  In this example, if the source_host field doesn't exist (the value is null) then it is set to "no_def"; if the value is the empty string it is set to "null"; otherwise, it's set to itself.

```
index="my_index" sourcetype=my_proj:my_logs 
| eval source_host = case(isnull(source_host), "no_def", source_host=="", "null", 1==1, source_host)
| stats count() by source_host
```

Answer (score 1):

The following searchv should do it. It creates a new field based on the presence or content of the source host field, and then you just so stats on that.

```
index="my_index" sourcetype=my_proj:my_logs | eval src_host=case(isnull(source_host),"Not defined", source_host="", "blank", true(), source_host) | stats count by src_host
```